# Control of Boxwood Psyllids

Tags: pest-control, boxwood

Do I have to use an insecticide spray or will a detergent like Dawn be just as effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing is everything here.  If you can apply a soap and water spray in early May before the characteristic leaf cupping damage occurs then you can reduce the population to a tolerable level if your soap and water can get good coverage where the nymphs are hiding.

Other [recommended solutions](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/insects/psyllids/boxwood-psyllid.aspx) are:

- do nothing, the damage is superficial and does not injure the plant
- prune out affected areas, you would probably be pruning your boxwood anyway
- pesticides are only recommended for severe infestations

Comment: I used one tablespoon of Dawn to one gallon of water.  They were in adult stage but I killed a ton of them.  They dropped like flies to the ground.  Hopefully I caught them to reduce the population for next year.